# Why the writer of this article divided the mean square error formula by 2 instead of MxN?

Tags: distribution-theory, machine-learning, mean-square-error

[The link of the article](https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2017/02/09/why-l2-blurry/), the intuition he made in his article is very convincing the understand the relation between mean square error and Gaussian distribution. but he changed the formula of the MSE to be divided by 2 instead of the number of pixels (MxN). which I don't understand is it for the reason of proving or it can be used in this way ?

Answer (score 0):

"where $M$ is the total number of examples".  Except for "images" in the title, there is no reference to pixels or images in this document.  His $L_2$ loss definition is for $M$ samples of $N$-dimensional vectors.  The $\frac{1}{2}$ here is a little strange, but if you use this scale factor in *all* your losses, it has no net effect -- half of bigger is still bigger than half of smaller.  If your model is pixels, these could be $N=1$ (intensity) or $N = 3$ (RGB), or other choices, and $M$ is the number of pixels.

Comment: Exactly right, the $1/2$ here is strange unless he really want to compare with the Gaussian. the $1/2$ is not used elsewhere it is already in the algorithm of Gaussian distribution. I still don't know if it can be considered ok or not ? even if we use N dimensional vector we should divide by N i guess ?

Comment: Don't divide by $N$.  $N$ is not a multiplier on the number of samples.  The number of samples is $M$, so you only divide by $M$ to get means.  If you have three of 1000 element vectors, you only divide by $3$ because you only have three samples per dimension.  (Note that measurements in different dimensions need not generally be in the same units, so trying to directly compare them is ... misguided.)

Comment: I'll take the first examples I have. http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/VELDHUIZEN/node18.html we divide by MN which they are the pixels counts or the element vectors.

Comment: Your new item has $M_{\text{Kristlandl}} = M_{\text{Veldhuizen}}N_{\text{Veldhuizen}}$ and $N_{\text{Kristlandl}} = 1$ since you have $M_{\text{Veldhuizen}}N_{\text{Veldhuizen}}$ samples of $1$-dimensional pixel intensities.

Comment: and this is the same case as in the article. measuring two images using MSE is done by subtracting each pixel of the same location and summing them then taking the average by diving it by the number of pixels which is (mXn)

Comment: the same hole if I factorize the image into N features(pixels) and instead of two images I have M samples.  So I need to divide by N and by M

Comment: "the article" is unintelligible in this context.  You have two articles.  The semantics of $M$ are different in the two articles.  If you insist they are the same, you will only confuse yourself.

Comment: could you help me seeing it better please ?

Comment: @Feras : Beyond telling you repeatedly that the $M$s are different, explaining what each $M$ is, and showing the relationship between them, all of which I have done, there does not seem to be any way to help you see this difference better.